# ReadOnly Property C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I want have readonly property in a Data Transfer Object,DTO object, without set; accessor like:

```
public class ViewBannerDTO
    {
        public int Id { get;  }
    }
```

but why get:

> 'ViewBannerDTO.Id.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors.

and also why i cant:

```
public readonly int Id{get;}
```

Comment: Just add `private set;`, wouldn't it do it?

Comment: If you define a getter and no setter for an automatic property then it could never ever return anything besides `0`.  What would be the point?

Comment: @Kilazur correct, but i want readonly

Comment: What do you think private is?

Comment: @Mohammadreza `private` is as close as you can get for an auto-implemented property - _something_ has to be able to set the property.

Comment: Private is not readonly. But once more, you can't do that with a property; you'd better be off using a simple public readonly member in fact, or implementing a property for this member, but in the end you will need a member. You got to know that automatic properties are just a nice shortcut for very simple properties; whenever you need something a bit fancier, you gotta get your hands dirty.

Comment: @Kilazur tnx yes, it whould do that

Comment: Related trick: Type `propfull` and press tab twice and implement. Resharper lets you change autos to with-backings in one click as well, which is nice. Also, no one has answered this question. `Readonly` (assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class) != `private` and using the wrong keyword is not a suitable alternative to typing a full property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have *no* setter for an auto-implemented property (otherwise how would you set it?).  You can either add a getter implementation (and a backing field if necessary) or use a `private` setter:

```
public class ViewBannerDTO
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
}
```

> Why i cant I do:
>
> ```
> public readonly int Id{get;}
> ```

because [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) only applies to *fields*.  You can accomplish the same thing with a property by using a `readonly` backing field and no `set` accessor:

```
private readonly int _Id;
public int Id {get { return _Id; } }
```

but you can't have a `readonly` auto-implement property because there's no syntax to initialize a property without a set accessor.

Comment: what is default access modifier for set in : public int Id {get;set;} in other word if it is public in default why compiler doesn't accept "public set;" In mind i read a property: define an integer variable and name it Id and define a public(implicitly) or private(must define explicitly) get and public(implicitly) or private(must define explicitly), so why i cant define public set explisitly

Comment: The default is the access level of the _property_.  You can only specify a level on the accessor if it overrides the access level of the property, but [there are restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd(v=vs.80).aspx) (a public setter on a private property makes no sense)

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly what is sais: There is not set accessor for that variable and you have no Get method implemented which can do stuff to get you a value.

Either go:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

OR

```
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            int something = GetStuffDone();
            return something;
        }
    }
```

Another something you can do is make the set function private like this:

```
public int Id { get; private set; }
```

And an answer to why you cant: The value will never be set cause it has no accessor.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a repeat of answers but OP does not understand

```
public class ViewBannerDTO
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public ViewBannerDTO () 
    {
         Id = 12;  // inside the class can assign private
                   // private not seen outside the classs 
    }
}
```

or you could

```
public class ViewBannerDTO
{
    private int id = 12;
    public int Id { get { return id; } }
}
```

or you could

```
public class ViewBannerDTO
{
    public int Id { get { return 12; }
}
```

Comment: tnx. what is default access modifier for set in : public int Id {get;set;} in other word if it is public in default  why compiler doesn't accept "public set;"

Comment: @Mohammadreza public int.  "public"  is the default.   You would need to ask Microsoft why you can't set it to public twice.

Comment: :) In mind i read a property: define an integer variable and name it Id and define a public(implicitly) or private(must define explicitly) get and public(implicitly) or private(must define explicitly), so why i cant define public set explisitly

Comment: Ask Microsoft. I did not write .NET.   Why do you need to set it explicitly?

Comment: :) D Stanley ,who answe this post, alsow answer this in comment: he accessibility level on the accessor must be more restrictive than the accessibility level on the property or indexer itself. <a href ="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd(v=vs.80).aspx">link</a>

Comment: @Mohammadreza I am not D Stanley.  I don't have a question.   Go away.

Answer (score 0):

As of C# 9 you can get read-only behavior by using an init accessor. Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; init;} = 1
    public int Baz { get; private init;} = 2
}

var foo = new Foo { Baz = 3};
```

In both cases the property can only be set during object construction. The private keyword ensures only the class can set the value, otherwise the caller of new can set the value with the object literal notation in the example.

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init